# If I start learning iOS development now, should I use the garbage collection feature?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management

....or should I learn to manage memory myself?

Is it OK to rely on the garbage collection feature of iOS 5?

I'm new and I'm thinking about learning iOS soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS doesn't have garbage collection; the iOS5 SDK introduced ARC (automatic reference counting), which is subtly different from real garbage collection. You'll still need to know and understand the semantics of reference counting, as avoiding memory leaks by not using strong reference cycles etc. is still **your** responsibility, even with ARC. But by all means, go ahead and use ARC, it does make most code simpler.

Comment: +1. ARC saves you from writing boilerplate memory management code, and it does some optimisations, but you still need to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify more ARC is compile time feature where compiler during compilation is adding code to release objects for you, so that as a developer you do not need to worry about that. On the other hand garbage collection is a run time feature which track all the reference counting for you and release any objects for which ref count is 0 automatically.

This is from Apple doc

> Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) for Objective-C makes memory
>   management the job of the compiler. By enabling ARC with the new Apple
>   LLVM compiler, you will never need to type retain or release again,
>   dramatically simplifying the development process, while reducing
>   crashes and memory leaks. The compiler has a complete understanding of
>   your objects, and releases each object the instant it is no longer
>   used, so apps run as fast as ever, with predictable, smooth
>   performance.

Use ARC for sure if you are planning to develop an app from start.